# Filtered Calculated columns behaving unexpectedly

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table in Power BI that has ratings, ids, and agent names. I'm using the DAX below to try and create a calculated column that shows me all articles rated at 3 or less but it's giving me amounts much higher.

```
TotalCountRated3OrLess = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(FILTER('ArticleFeedbackExternal', 'ArticleFeedbackExternal'[result] <= 3)),
    ALLEXCEPT('ArticleFeedbackExternal', 'ArticleFeedbackExternal'[article_id])
)
```

Example:

| article_id | result |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 |
| 10 | 1 |
| 10 | 2 |
| 10 | 1 |
| 10 | 5 |

What I end up seeing

| article_id | result | Times less than 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | 15 |
| 10 | 1 | 15 |
| 10 | 2 | 15 |
| 10 | 1 | 15 |
| 10 | 5 | 15 |

I'm expecting to see 4 for each row under Times less than 3 but the numbers are off. Bear in mind, I have this exact type of column and formula on another table for a different page in the report and it works but I'm having to use Sum aggregation or otherwise it performs the same way as the one I listed above.

TotalCountRated3OrLess =
CALCULATE(
COUNTROWS(FILTER('ArticleFeedbackExternal', 'ArticleFeedbackExternal'[result] <= 3)),
ALLEXCEPT('ArticleFeedbackExternal', 'ArticleFeedbackExternal'[article_id])
)

I also have a field for the amount of times an article is scored 4 or 5 but I don't have this issue at all when I use the same formula on either page.

TotalCountRated4Or5 =
CALCULATE(
COUNTROWS(FILTER('ArticleFeedbackExternal', 'ArticleFeedbackExternal'[result] IN {4, 5})),
ALLEXCEPT('ArticleFeedbackExternal', 'ArticleFeedbackExternal'[article_id])
)

I'm sure I'm overlooking something simple but I just can't see it.

Comment: I got correct results with your DAX formula. Trim the result column and try again